# Why do the four points experience identical electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, gauss-law

**The question:**
[image: The question]

**The answer and explanation given:**

> Brent is wrong. The net force is perpendicular and away from the sheet. Components of the forces acting in any other direction cancel each other out. Since the charge is uniformly distributed and the sheet is infinite, all the field vectors have the same magnitude, and 
> are parallel. Hence the density of field lines does not change with distance from the sheet, so the magnitude of the field is constant. See below

**I don't understand the explanation. I applied Gaussian surface to calculate the flux at each point (A and B are on the same surface, C and D on another surface), and below is my diagram, wherein, the two cylinders have the same lengths l, but different radius rAB and rCD:**

[image: my diagram]

**Then my calculation steps:**
[image: my calculation steps]

May someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to PSE.  Your question concerns an infinite sheet of uniform surface charge density $\:\sigma\:$ and not an infinite straight line with uniform linear charge density $\:\lambda$.

Comment: Please don't post images in place of text and mathematical equations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your diagram doesn't match the question! It's a sheet of charge and your diagram has a line. If you repeat the Gaussian surface calculation with a short cylinder, base on the sheet and finishing at A and B in one case, or C and D in the other case then you soon see the given argument is correct

Answer (score -1):

It’s an infinite plane of charge, not an infinite line of charge. For the application of Gauss' law to a sheet of charge, see:http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elesht.html#c1

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know it's useless to ask, by why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I'd guess it's because you should not post answers to homework questions.